# I'm struggling with writing a program that will extract the largest K values from a long list of input values

Tags: python

HELP! I'm struggling with writing a program that will extract the largest K values from a long list of input values. The single argument is an integer that specifies how many values to extract from the input data.
Call this value K. Your program will then read any number of input data items from standard
input ubtil end-of-file. Once end-of-file hase been reached, your program will then print out the
largest K values it captured from the input data elements.
Keep in mind that your program may be given very large amounts of data, so it will not be practical
for your program to try to hold onto all of the input data until end-of-file has been reached.

```
class MinHeap:

def _init_(self):
    self.list = [ ]

def swap(self, i, j):
    temp = self.list[i]
    self.list[i] = self.list[j]
    self.list[j] = temp

def siftUp(self, pos):
    i = pos;
    while i > 0:
        parent = (i - 1) // 2
        if self.list[parent] > self.list[i]:
            self.swap(parent, i)
        else:
            break
            i = parent
    return self

def siftDown(self, lo, hi):
    i = lo
    child = 2*i + 1
    while child <= hi:
        rchild = child + 1
        if rchild <= hi and self.list[child] > self.list[rchild]:
            child = rchild
        if self.list[i] > self.list[child]:
            self.swap(i, child)
        else:
            break
            i = child
            child = 2*i +1
        return self

def getMin(self):
    if len(self.list) <= 0:
        return None
    else:
        return self.list[0]

def removeMin(self):
    if len(self.list) <= 0:
        return None
    else:
        self.swap(0, -1)
```

Comment: Just so you know, swapping variable values in Python has an idiom: `a,b = b,a` should work without a `temp` variable. So suppose you have a list `lst` (don't name your lists `list` because that will shadow the built-in function). Then to swap the values at the first two positions, you could do: `lst[0],lst[1] = lst[1],lst[0]`

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Oveflow! This question is likely not going to get a good reception because it falls under the "Why isn't my code working" category. Please see this link on how to create a [complete, minimal, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and try to edit your question. You should also check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).